# Check if next char is {

Tags: conditionals, latex-base

Using `\@ifnextchar` one can detect if *e.g.* the next Character is a `[`, *e.g.*:

```
\@ifnextchar[%
{
    %% code to execute if [ scanned.
}{
    %% code to execute if [ scanned.
}
```

However, I can’t seem to use `\@ifnextchar{`
to test if the next Character is `{`.

Is there any way to use `\@ifnextchar` to detect a `{`?

Is there any way at all to detect a `{`?

If so, please let me know.

---

**Update 1:**
Okay, I think that **\bgroup** is a successful Answer. I think I know now (sort of) why it didn’t work when I first used it.

The Purpose I needed it for was to be able to have a Macro that can take an indefinite Number of Arguments. (*E.g.* listing out Authors.) These seems to run into issues once we want to place the resulting String in an Header.

---

**Update 2:**
Regarding my secondary Problem (which was my original Application for all of this), is there a way to **delay** Commands in TeX. In particular, I want to first run a Macro which *waits for an arbitrary Amount of Arguments*, **then** run a second Command on this.

Here is the kind of thing I’m trying to do:

`\def\headerauth#1{\rhead{#1\ifnextchar\bgroup{\@headerauth}{.}}}`

`\def\@headerauth#1{\& #1\ifnextchar\bgroup{\@headerauth}{.}}}`

Without the `\rhead`, Things work fine. But once I use `\rhead`, it will only read the first Argument. The others are ignored. *E.g.*

`\headerauth{S. Mishkin}{L. Polotov}`

results in *»S. Mishkin.«* being placed in the Header, and *»L. Polotov«* placed in the main Text.

Whereas if I define `\headerauth` **omitting** the `\rhead`, and then use:

`\rhead{\headerauth{S. Mishkin}{L. Polotov}}`

I obtain *»S. Mishkin & L. Polotov.«* in the Header as desired.

Why doesn’t the first Thing work? (I realise that this Question probably belongs to a new Topic…)

***P.s.*** **@doncherry** & **@Yossi Farjoun**: I’ve figured it out — turns out I was using the wrong Key Combination to access the ` Symbol on my Keyboard. (The same Key produces `'˚´ depending on Key Combinations.) (Took me a short while to figure out how to quote-not-use the Symbol ` (as well as \) via \` and \\ — ah, the Standard coding Tricks. Glad to see it’s very logical.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: This question should probably be tagged with [tag:tex-core] or [tag:latex-kernel], I don't know which one is appropriate.

Comment: @doncherry I'd agree: the question is about the LaTeX kernel, I guess, but the reasoning is a TeX core concept.

Comment: @R47: Sorry if I wasn't clear: Your block code had already been properly marked as code; if you look at [revision 2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/33455/revisions), I inserted backticks `\`` (not apostrophes `'`) where you referred to code within a line of normal text; so the source code of your first few words is ``Using `\@ifnextchar` one``. For more information, check out http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code, and http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks.

Comment: Yes I knew you meant that Symbol. It’s just that on my Keyboard the Button which looks like the Backtick seems to produce '. I have ‘'´ but no Backtick, sorry.

Comment: @JosephWright IMHO better to use both tags for these with latex-kernel first.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: You can't influence the order of the tags, [tag:tex-core] will likely stay the first tag for a while: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87508/are-the-tags-shown-in-a-particular-order

Comment: @R47: Then you could always copy-and-paste the backtick from any of the pages I referred to you.

Comment: @R47:not having the backtick could be a problem for someone who wants to use LaTeX...I suggest that you find a keyboard layout (or keyboard) that has one...

Answer (score 27):

```
\@ifnextchar\bgroup
```

See the definition of `\input` in the kernel:

```
\def\input{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\@iinput\@@input}
```

where `\@iinput` is able to cope with `\input{file}` and `\@@input` is an alias for the primitive `\input` so `\input file` will be processed as well.

`\@ifnextchar` has three arguments: (1) the token to be looked for, (2) what to do if it's found, and (3) what to do if the token is not there. After storing the arguments, it makes TeX look at the following *token* (not argument) and compares it (with `\ifx`) to the stored first argument. In case `#1` is `\bgroup` it compares successfully to an open brace because of the statement given in the kernel

```
\let\bgroup={
```

This doesn't mean that `\bgroup` can be always used as a substitute for an open brace; it's allowed for this purpose only in some particular cases. This is exploited, for instance, in the definition of `minipage` or `lrbox`. For comparison purposes, `\bgroup` is the right substitute of `{`, as it can be seen by TeX as an argument for a macro.

Suppose we want to do something different when macro `\xyz` is followed by an open brace or not; say we want to support the syntaxes

```
\xyz{abc}
\xyz abc\stopxyz
```

using `abc` as the argument. Then we would do

```
\newcommand{\xyz}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\@xyzb\@xyz}
\def\@xyz#1\stopxyz{\@xyzb{#1}}
\def\@xyzb#1{do something with #1}
```

This can also be used to define a macro with an "unknown" number of arguments, say a list of authors to go in the header:

```
\def\authorslist{\ignorespaces} % initialization
\def\authors#1{\g@addto@macro\authorslist{ #1}\@ifnextchar\bgroup\authors{}}

\fancyhead[R]{\authorslist}
```

The macro `\authors` appends its argument to the list (initialized so as to ignore the space before the first author) and then execute again itself until there's not a brace any more (when it does nothing).

Comment: Here, `\bgroup` is an 'implicit' token. It's a copy of `{`, but as it is not `{` does not count toward the number of braces used in the 'container' macro, so can be used in places where `{` cannot. Also, `\@ifnextchar` needs to be able to absorb the search token as an argument, which again requires that you don't use a literal `{`.

Comment: I tried \bgroup, but yield no luck. I used

'\def\test#1{#1 \@ifnextchar\bgroup{yes}{no}}
'\test{first}{second}

which outputs:

'first no

Comment: @R47 See edited answer

Comment: Okay, that one works now: I had made some other mistake. But I still cannot yield any success with the following:


'\def\authors#1{\fancyhead[R]{#1 \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\@einmehr}{}}}
'\def\@einmehr#1{\& #1 \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\@einmehr}{}}}

Comment: @R47 Please, edit your original question instead of putting code in comments.

Comment: You can find a real example in the definition of `frame` environment of `beamer` class. See the definition of `\beamer@checkframetitle` in `beamerbaseframe.sty`.

Comment: @R47: Usually `\@ifnextchar\bgroup` is the way to go, but keep in mind that this also works if the macro is followed by `\bgroup` not only by `{`. I have code in my `collcell` package where I first do this test, then read the next token and check if it is `\bgroup` or something else. In the second case it really was a `{`.