# Automating processing of trailing punctuation (if any) for hyperlinks

Tags: macros, hyperref, punctuation

This is a follow-up to [Should Hyperlinks include trailing puctuation as part of the link text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125357/should-hyperlinks-include-trailing-puctuation-as-part-of-the-link-text), and this question is about automating the processing of the trailing character.  I would like to be able to have the punctuation be specified *after* the macro as in:

```
\CreateLink{<linke style>}{<link target>}{<link text>},
```

where I have used a comma as an example.
I prefer the above instead of:

```
\CreateLink{<linke style>}{<link target>}{<link text>,}
```

for two reasons:

1. It is more readable (punctuation is more obvious in the code).
2. Allows me to defer the decision of the weather to include the punctuation as part of the link text or not.

So, I would like to modify the `\CreateLink` macro to be able to check if the subsequent character is a space or not. If not, then consider the next character as punctuation and include that character in the output of `\CreateLink`.

I realize that the solution will probably involve `\@ifnextchar` but I was not able able to get that to work. In the attempt below I output a `-` if a non-space character is found. Since the `-` is in the output for all cases, my attempt is clearly missing something.

[image]

### References:

- [Check if next char is {](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33455/check-if-next-char-is)

### Code:

```
% The following \def allows to have one version of this code for this questions,
% and the previous question at:
% 
%    https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125357/should-hyperlinks-include-trailing-puctuation-as-part-of-the-link-text
%
\def\SmartVersion{}%  Should be uncommented for this question.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%%                https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/
%%                    underline-omitting-the-descenders
%%
%%
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new:Npn \white_text:n #1
      {
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {.01}
        \fp_mul:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {#1}
        \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
        \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{-\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
      }
    \NewDocumentCommand{\whiten}{ m }
        {
          \int_step_function:nnnN {1}{1}{#1} \white_text:n
        }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{ \varul }{ D<>{5} O{0.2ex} O{0.1ex} +m } {%
\begingroup
\setul{#2}{#3}%
\def\SOUL@uleverysyllable{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{\the\SOUL@syllable}%
   \ifdim\dp0>\z@
      \SOUL@ulunderline{\phantom{\the\SOUL@syllable}}%
      \whiten{#1}%
      \llap{%
        \the\SOUL@syllable
        \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
      }%
   \else
       \SOUL@ulunderline{%
         \the\SOUL@syllable
         \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
       }%
   \fi}%
    \ul{#4}%
\endgroup
}%
\makeatother
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\CreateLinkA}[2]{%
    \hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}, urlcolor=.}%
    \href{#1}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand{\CreateLinkB}[2]{%
    \hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}, urlcolor=red}%
    \href{#1}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand{\CreateLinkC}[2]{%
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=false,urlcolor=.}%
    \setulcolor{blue}%
    \href{#1}{\varul[0.5pt][1.0pt]{#2}}%
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\CreateLink}[3]{%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{\CreateLinkA{#2}{#3}}%
        {2}{\CreateLinkB{#2}{#3}}%
        {3}{\CreateLinkC{#2}{#3}}%
    }%
    \ifdefined\SmartVersion% 
        % If the next character is anything other than a space, 
        % include that char as part of the text. 
        % The "-" is supposed to whatever the next character is,
        % but don't know how to get that character.  
        % Note that the "-" is shown in all cases, so this is NOT working.
        \@ifnextchar{\space}{\space}{-}%
    \else% "ELSE" clause is unused in this question
        \xspace%
    \fi
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\textbf{Punctuation NOT part of link:}\medskip
\par Go and check out \CreateLink{1}{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}, and also\ldots
\par Go and check out \CreateLink{2}{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}, and also\ldots
\par Go and check out \CreateLink{3}{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}, and also\ldots

\bigskip
\textbf{Punctuation part of link:}\medskip
\par Go and check out \CreateLink{1}{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo,} and also\ldots
\par Go and check out \CreateLink{2}{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo,} and also\ldots
\par Go and check out \CreateLink{3}{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo,} and also\ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick comment: `\@ifnextchar{\space}...` actually checks for the presence of a macro containing a space (since `\space` is a macro containing a space).  Replacing by `\@ifnextchar\@sptoken` would not work either for a different reason: `\@ifnextchar` ignores spaces _before_ comparing what follows with its first argument.  Plenty of packages have probably fixed this oversight, but since you are using `expl3`, I'd suggest going for `\peek_catcode:NTF \c_space_token { } { - }` or similar (see documentation of `l3token`).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Embarrassed to say this, but I am only using `expl3` due to all the wonderful solutions I have obtained from this site. I am still clueless about `expl3` and don't think I could easily adapt your suggestion. But will have to tackle it if a solution does not show up when this bounty ends.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a try.

The following code only uses your first link style as the different styles didn't seem to be essential for the question. It uses the packages [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) for its list processing tools and its `\ifblank` macro, and Heiko Oberdiek's [`ltxcmds`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxcmds) for its `\ltx@ifnextchar` that allows for checking a following space via `\ltx@ifnextchar{ }{<true>}{<false>}`.

The `\CreateLink{<address>}{<text>}` macro below checks if a space follows. If not the next token is taken and it is checked if it is in a list of tokens that is set with `\setlinkpunctuation{<punctuation marks>}`. This macro gives you full control which punctuation mark should be included in the link.

We get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox,ltxcmds}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% list parser with no separator:
\DeclareListParser*\@add@punctuation{}
% set the punctuation list (the parser does not like blank lists):
\def\setlinkpunctuation#1{%
  \def\@punctuation{}%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {}
    {\@add@punctuation{\listadd\@punctuation}{#1}}%
}

% check if a space follows; if yes, only create the link, else
% eat the next token:
\newcommand*\CreateLink[2]{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar{ }
    {\@create@link{#1}{#2}{}}
    {\@create@link{#1}{#2}}%
}

% check if #3 is among the punctuation marks
% and either place it inside the link or outside:
\def\@create@link#1#2#3{%
  \ifinlist{#3}{\@punctuation}
    {\@create@actual@link{#1}{#2#3}}
    {\@create@actual@link{#1}{#2}#3}%
}

% the actual link:
\def\@create@actual@link#1#2{%
  \hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}, urlcolor=.}%
  \href{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

only \texttt{,}\par\medskip
\setlinkpunctuation{,}
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}, and also\ldots\par
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo} and also\ldots\par
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}. and also\ldots\par
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}! and also\ldots\par

\bigskip
nothing\par\medskip
\setlinkpunctuation{}
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}, and also\ldots\par
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo} and also\ldots\par
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}. and also\ldots\par
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}! and also\ldots\par

\bigskip
\texttt{,.} and \texttt{!}\par\medskip
\setlinkpunctuation{.,!}
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}, and also\ldots\par
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo} and also\ldots\par
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}. and also\ldots\par
Go and check out \CreateLink{www.yahoo.com}{the yahoo}! and also\ldots\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to be working great.

Comment: Dear downvoter: thanks for your criticism! :) I'd very much appreciate id, though, if you'd left a comment explaining why you downvoted my answer. I would be able to improve it then. Instead I am unfortunately clueless...

Comment: Some people will do that.  What can you do?  I wish @downvoter would ping them though.

Comment: @cgnieder: The question also got voted down, so perhaps a new user. Haven't integrated your code into my actual use case yet, but just realized that you have two `\makeatletter` so perhaps the downvoter was complaining about that?

Comment: @PeterGrill Oh! That should have been a `\makeatother`, of course! I corrected it.