# Automatic upright subscripts in pdflatex

Tags: math-mode, automation

For some time I used [Micos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303835/21557) solution to the [problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156641/21557) of automatically typesetting subscripts upright based on lualatex. Now I want to switch back to pdflatex (because of compile times and the better preformat/mylatexformat support) but preserve the syntax provided by this solution.

In this [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156963/21557) answer @Svend Tveskæg showed a solution which works also with pdflatex, but with a slightly different syntax. Now I want to modify this solution to behave like Micos solutions but works with pdflatex.

In particular it should use `{` and `}` as delimiters (instead of `|`) and also switches back to italic if I leave a gap like `$v_ {x,\max}$`.

I tried to replace the delimiters in @Svend Tveskæg like this, but it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
 \begingroup
  \catcode`\_=\active
  \protected\gdef_{\@ifnextchar{\subtextup\sb}
 \endgroup
\def\subtextup\catcode{#1}{\sb{\textnormal{#1}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=32768}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A_1 A_p A_{p} A_ {p} $

\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Upright.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-21>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
! Illegal parameter number in definition of _.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.8 \def\subtextup\catcode{#1
                             }{\sb{\textnormal{#1}}}
```

Here is what I used so far:

```
% Automatically upright subscripts with lualatex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{uprightsub}
  [2021/09/06 v1.0 upright math via lualatex]


\RequirePackage{amsmath,luacode}

%%See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156641/typeset-subscript-material-automatically-in-upright-font-shape

\begin{luacode}
function up_subs ( buff )
    return ( string.gsub ( buff , "_(%b{})" , "_{\\textnormal%1}" ) )
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
"process_input_buffer", up_subs, "up_subs")}}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `uprightsub.sty'.
```

If there is another pdflatex solution which shows the desired behavior it would be also welcome.

*Edit*

If I compile use the lualatex solution like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{uprightsub}

\begin{document}

$A_1 A_p A_{p} A_ {p} $

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

which would be the desired output for this example.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't understand TeX, you're going to have a bad time trying to modify TeX code.

Anyway, just do this (use `nospace` version to "respect" spaces)

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\makeatletter
 \begingroup
  \catcode`\_=\active
  \protected\gdef_{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace\bgroup\subtextup\sb}
 \endgroup
\def\subtextup#1{\sb{\textnormal{#1}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=32768}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A_1 A_p A_{p} A_ {p} $

\end{document}
```

If I understood correctly this output [image: the output] should be what you want.

Comment: Credit to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405608/ifnextchar-considering-whitespace for the nospace version of the macro.

Comment: See [conditionals - Check if next char is { - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33455/check-if-next-char-is) for explanation of the `bgroup` thing.

Comment: For learning TeX programming resources are in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668/250119. (warning very complicated and esoteric)

Comment: Thanks, I think that's almost what I want except of one detail. If I compile the same line with the upright.sty file I used so far, the third p is slightly smaller, however in both cases `\textnormal` was used. Do have an idea why?

Comment: @Julia What `upright.sty` are you talking about?

Comment: My own `sty` file I posted in my original message.

Comment: @Julia Amsmath patches some LaTeX commands to make them math-style-aware apparently. Just use the package and problem is fixed.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Works.

Comment: @Julia I'd use `\mathrm` instead of `\textnormal`. The latter might not always do what you want/expect.